# Как открыть список контактов по ссылке? Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Подскажите, как по ссылке открыть список контактов телеграм, чтобы пригласить в группу?

Сделал так, но пишет, -  "ссылка устарела", а мне нужно, чтобы открывалось окно с контактами телеграм, чтобы пользователь отметил контакты и добавил в группу.

```html
await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"\n\nПригласить, свои контакты, можно нажав <a href='https://t.me/joinchat/url?url=https%3A//t.me/urlgruppytg'>сюда</a>.".format(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id), parse_mode='html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ссылка на приглашение устарела, то вы можете создать новую ссылку приглашения, используя функцию `export_chat_invite_link()` библиотеки [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot).

Пример кода для создания новой ссылки на приглашение в группу:

```
import telegram

# Устанавливаем токен бота и создаем объект бота
bot_token = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'
bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)

# Получаем идентификатор группы
group_id = 'YOUR_GROUP_ID'

# Создаем новую ссылку на приглашение в группу
new_invite_link = bot.export_chat_invite_link(chat_id=group_id)

# Отправляем сообщение с новой ссылкой на приглашение в группу
message = f'Пригласить свои контакты можно по ссылке: {new_invite_link}'
bot.send_message(chat_id=group_id, text=message)
```

В этом примере мы сначала получаем идентификатор группы `group_id`. Затем мы используем метод `export_chat_invite_link()` для создания новой ссылки на приглашение в группу.

После этого мы формируем текст сообщения с новой ссылкой на приглашение и используем метод `send_message()` для отправки сообщения в группу с заданным идентификатором `group_id`.

Таким образом, после выполнения данного кода вы должны получить сообщение в группе с новой ссылкой на приглашение.

Comment: Спасибо, переделал для Aiogram а как сделать, чтобы нажав, на надпись, открывались контакты и пользователь, отметил и контакты добавились в группу?